# How to resolve "IO-fout: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"" error?

Tags: java, ojdbc

I am trying to make a DB connection to one of my DB. But it is throwing me error:
`IO-fout: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"`

I am not getting any clue for this.

1.I upgraded my DB to 12c as per my project requirement
2.Updated from `ojdbc14.jar` to `ojdbc6`
3.Tried adding sid also but it is still giving the same error

```
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc";                      
DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());   
res =DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
```

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO-fout: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"    
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)   
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:711)   
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)   
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)   
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:558)   
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)   
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: :@abc => there seems to be your problem. looks like you should either remove the :, or that block all together

Comment: is your url similar to this: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:sid`